# XAML rectangle not expanding

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a rectangle that is expanding just fine horizontally, but not vertically:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" x:Name="Scenario4ImageContainer" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

When I set the MinHeight property to 700 it takes up all the screen space, but I want to take up however much room it can get.

Also this outer grid sits inside of this parent grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" Background="#1D1D1D" Margin="0,2,0,-2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried out the XAML you posted and the `Rectangle` is expanding just fine. The only thing limiting it is the outer `Grid` which defines two rows of equal height. Try making the second row narrower and you'll see the `Rectangle` expand:

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" Background="#1D1D1D" Margin="0,2,0,-2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="MainDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" x:Name="Scenario4ImageContainer" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```